# How to read a tuple with python pandas and How Series.replace function works

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read a file with `read_table`.Every row of the file is a tuple,Like
`('20151130','10',...,'23')`. I set `dataset = read_table(filename,names = ['date',...,'number'])`.And I get `dataset['date'] = ('20151130'`...

So I want to delete "(" in "('20151130'". But `dataset['date'].replace("(","")` do not work on every element in dataset['date']. I just use a loop to finish it.

```
for i in xrange(N):
    dataset_1.append(dataset['date'][i].replace("(",""))
```

How can I read a tuple easily? And why Series.replace can't work on every element  with default?Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method of dataframe or series doesn't work in your case because it's trying to find string that match whole pattern which you are set in the `to_replace` parameter. If you'd like to match part of your pattern you could specify `regex=True` and then set your pattern as regex expression:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
('20151130','10','23')
('20151129', '11', '20')
"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(data), sep=',', header=None)
df1 = df.replace(to_replace="\(|\)", value="", regex=True)

In [168]: df
Out[168]:
             0      1       2
0  ('20151130'   '10'   '23')
1  ('20151129'   '11'   '20')

In [171]: df1
Out[171]:
            0      1      2
0  '20151130'   '10'   '23'
1  '20151129'   '11'   '20'
```

If you want to use the same `replace` method for Series for particular column you could use:

```
In [174]: df[0]
Out[174]:
0    ('20151130'
1    ('20151129'
Name: 0, dtype: object

In [175]: df[0].replace(to_replace="\(", value="", regex=True)
Out[175]:
0    '20151130'
1    '20151129'
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

**EDIT**

Also you could try use `str.replace` method of pandas.Series:

```
df[0].str.replace("(", "")

In [182]: df[0].str.replace('(', '')
Out[182]:
0    '20151130'
1    '20151129'
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you. The replace method  regex=True:  TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'regex'.Pyhton 2.7 My python version is too old.

Comment: I find a method to do this.

Comment: I find a method to do this. Define a function and use Series.map. For example, def f(x): x.replace("(",""). df[0].map(f). That worked.

Comment: yes, but it's almost the same as `df[0].str.replace`. Would you to add that statement to the answer?

Comment: I have tried. df[0].str.replace() there is a error :<sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis>,so I found another way. Diffrent verion leads this?

Comment: @PengHe look to the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and find your version. Than bullet with "Working with text data"